# (Step Functions Activity Worker) Best practice for handling long polling timeouts in boto?

Tags: python, boto3, long-polling, aws-step-functions

I am working on my first Step Functions Activity Worker (EC2). Predictably, after 5 minutes of long polling with no activity from the Step Functions state machine, the client connection times out with the error:

**botocore.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: Read timeout on endpoint URL: "https://states.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/"**

Would it be better to catch the error and retry the long poll (every 5 minutes when no activity is present), or try to terminate the call early and retry before the error? I've thought about using a different type of loop, but I want to maximize the value of long polling and not repeatedly request against the Step Functions API (although if that's the best way I'll do it).

Thank you,

Andrew

```
import boto3
import time
import json

region = 'us-east-1'
activity_arn = 'arn:aws:states:us-east-1:754112345676:activity:Process_Imagery' 

while True:
    client = boto3.client('stepfunctions', region_name=region)
    response = client.get_activity_task(activityArn=activity_arn,
                                    workerName='imagery_processor')    
    activity_token = response['taskToken']
    input_params = json.loads(response['input'])

    print("================")
    print(input_params)
    client.send_task_success(taskToken=activity_token, output='true')
```

Comment: I did some more testing today (packet capture), which showed the instance and Step Functions API communicating just about every 1 minute before Botocore eventually kills the attempt (~5 min).  This leads me to believe I need to handle the NULL return better.  Will research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I answered my own question here.  The [AWS documentation states](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/stepfunctions.html#SFN.Client.get_activity_task): 
"The maximum time the service holds on to the request before responding is 60 seconds. If no task is available within 60 seconds, the poll returns a taskToken with a null string."

However, instead of string being returned, I believe the JSON response from StepFunctions has no 'taskToken' at all.  This while loop works:

```
import boto3
import time
import json
from botocore.config import Config as BotoCoreConfig

region = 'us-east-1'
boto_config = BotoCoreConfig(read_timeout=70, region_name=region)
sf_client = boto3.client('stepfunctions', config=boto_config)
activity_arn = 'arn:aws:states:us-east-1:754185699999:activity:Process_Imagery'  

while True:
    response = sf_client.get_activity_task(activityArn=activity_arn,
                                    workerName='imagery_processor')    

    if 'taskToken' not in response:
        print('No Task Token')
        # time.sleep(2)
    else:
        print(response['taskToken']) 
        print("===================")
        activity_token = response['taskToken']
        sf_client.send_task_success(taskToken=activity_token, output='true')
```